# exception java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException:

Tags: java, exceção, wildfly

Boa tarde,

Ando de volta de um projecto JEE onde utilizado jms e o servidor é o wildfly 8.0. Já ando de volta desta excepção há algum tempo mas ainda não consegui resolver. Penso que não me falte nenhuma configuração no jboss mas sinceramente já me faltam ideias.. alguém que tenha mais experiência que me possa ajudar.

[image: stracktrace eclipse]

Ele parece arrebentar nesta zona do código:

```
Document doc;
doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Element main = doc.getElementById("main");
Elements links = main.getElementsByClass("overview-top");
```

Código java de ligação de conexão ao servidor:

```
connectionFactoryLookupAddress = new String("jms/RemoteConnectionFactory");
destinationLookupAddress = new String("jms/topic/Catalog");
environment = new Properties();
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "testuser");
environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "is");
environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,  "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");
environment.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);
InitialContext iCtx = new InitialContext(environment);

this.cf = (ConnectionFactory) iCtx.lookup(connectionFactoryLookupAddress);
this.t = (Destination) iCtx.lookup(destinationLookupAddress);
this.c = this.cf.createConnection(environment.getProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL),
environment.getProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS));
this.c.start();
this.s = this.c.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
this.mp = this.s.createProducer(this.t);
```

O log do Widfly:

[image: Wildfly Log]

Alguém que me consiga dar alguma dica ?

Obrigado pela atenção

Comment: Você pode postar o stacktrace completo?

Comment: Editei o post com descrição maior do stacktrace.

Comment: Não tenho ideia do que pode ser. Faça uma cópia do seu projeto, e tente ir desmontando e reduzindo a aplicação, pedaço por pedaço, até ter uma aplicação mínima cuja única finalidade seja a de demonstrar o problema e de onde mais nada possa ser retirado. Quando conseguir isso, você provavelmente vai acabar ou entendendo o problema, ou achando uma forma de eliminá-lo, ou isolar a sua causa.

Comment: Ok, brigado na mesma. Já andei aqui de volta, mas está dificil.. é que só acontece uma vez, tenho várias thread que continuam a trabalhar normalmente.. só a primeira vez que executa o do Jsoup que ele dá a excepção, as outras funciona sem problemas .. mas vou continuar por aqui a tentar ;)

Comment: O erro é realmente bem estranho. Creio que você deve estar enganado quanto ao erro no trecho do Jsoup, pois não há nada ali que possa causa essa exceção, a não ser que o trecho esteja sendo executado dentro de um EJB e o log está mascarando a exceção original. Uma das formas de identificar o problema com erros misteriosos é colocar `try/catch` em tudo e logar manualmente os possíveis erros, pois às vezes os frameworks capturam uma exceção e lançam outra que não tem nada a ver com a original.

Comment: Sim, também não me parece do ksoup, mas decide partilhar onde ele realmente estoura. Se bem que é um mundo multi thread por isso nd disso é muito certo. O problema não terá relação com timeout's do widlfly ? Já ouvi essa dica pela internet mas o que configurei não me pareceu por ai... ainda vou voltar a exp mais try{} catch .. mas voltar a desmontar o código..

Comment: Já andei de volta do código.. Pelo que percebo têm relação com configuração do widlfly.. Porque já comentei parte do código e reparei que a excepção acontece quando o código é algo mais demorado. Parece me que é problema de compatibilidade de versões.. mas ainda não sei ao certo ..